# Wordpress + Jquery Accordion + font-awesome plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, font-awesome, accordion

I've created a plugin in wordpress that creates a jquery accordion.

It's working fine, however, now I'm trying to add icons using font-awesome, but I don't seem to be able to get the icons to show.

I've added the 'font-awesome' plugin and have verified that icons show up elsewhere simply by specifying the icon class in an empty element *(i, div, span)*.  So, I know it is there and working.

I'm instantiating the accordion like so:

```
let expanderWidgets = $('.article-sidebar-column .expander')
if (expanderWidgets.length > 0) {
  expanderWidgets.accordion({
    icons: {header: "fas fa-caret-right", activeHeader: "fas fa-caret-down"},
    collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content"
  })
```

In the inspector, I can see it inserts the 'fa*' classes in a span in the h3 header, so they are there, however their width is 0, so it doesn't look like the icons are getting loaded.

Is there some extra enqueue or other initialization I need to do in the plugin to get the fa icons to show?

(I'd rather use the fa icons than the jquery icons - don't want to load a jq ui theme and I don't want yet another font set in the wp install - it's bloated enough, already)

Answer (score 0):

Crickets on this.

I finally gave up and used a jquery ui font package.

It works.